# MongoDB: return a document if another does not exist

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am struggling to find a good way of executing a compound MongoDB `find()` with the following criteria:

- Query will match one document based on search criteria
- If a match is a found, that document will be returned
- If a match is NOT found, another document would be returned in is place.  This second document would match another set of criteria
- The query would ideally return exactly one record no matter what.

In my particular case, I have a collection of `users` which contains a list of users and their associated permissions.  It also contains a special entry for a `guest` pseudo-user that contain default permissions.  This `guest` document is the one that needs to be returned if an exact user match does not take place.

I have tried using `{$or: [ { id: "bob" }, {id: "guest" } ]}` as well as `{ id: { $in: [ "bob", "guest" ] } }`, but both of these search the collection sequentially and would return either "bob" or "guest" depending on which was inserted first.

Is there a way to explicitly say find `bob` or as a fallback, return the `guest` document?

Keep in mind this would be executed from Node.js, hence I'm looking for a clean & simple way to offload this to MongoDB.

I realize this can be done as two queries, but I would like to avoid that scenario if possible.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

if you insert `guest` as the first object, then by combination of `limit` and `sort` by _id you can solve this!

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of using find({}), you can use aggregate and in that $in and $cond operator can solve your problem.
You can refer to this link->
https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/

Comment: hmm, I didn't know `$cond` existed.  That might just do it, though the end result would be very long.  I wonder if there is an alternate way without aggregation...